# How to build aspectj project using maven?

Tags: java, maven, aspectj

I have created a Aspectj Project in Eclipse ide but i need to build it using maven.

I have maven-aspectj plugin but don't know how to use it.

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610633/maven-compile-aspectj-project-containing-java-1-6-source

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven + AspectJ - all steps to configure it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423965/maven-aspectj-all-steps-to-configure-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are the steps that I followed to get this working. This gave me [compile-time weaving](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/ltw.html). If you need other strategies, clearly you need another approach (such as [Spring AOP](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.5/reference/aop.html) for runtime AOP proxies).

1. Add a property to standardize the AspectJ version that you use:

   ```
   <properties>
       <aspectj.version>1.7.2</aspectj.version>
     ...
   ```
2. Add the runtime dependency:

   ```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
     <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
     <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. Add the AspectJ Maven plugin:

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
       <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>1.4</version>
       <executions>
         <execution>
           <goals>
             <goal>compile</goal>
             <goal>test-compile</goal>
           </goals>
         </execution>
       </executions>
       <dependencies>
         <dependency>
           <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
           <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
           <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
           <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
           <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
           <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
         </dependency>
       </dependencies>
       <configuration>
         <source>1.7</source>
         <target>1.7</target>
         <forceAjcCompile>true</forceAjcCompile>
       </configuration>
     </plugin>
   ```

I'm not sure if `forceAjcCompile` makes a lot of sense, really, but I've seen some cases where the aspects weren't consistently applied. I'm blaming this (for now) on Eclipse overwriting class files or something, hence the `forceAjcCompile`.

Additional things I did:

1. Add `src/main/aspects` as an extra source directory (`build-helper-maven-plugin` plugin). Just because it looks good in Eclipse
2. Add a `pluginExecution`/`pluginExecutionFilter` for the AspectJ plugin ([`lifecycle-mapping` plugin](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered#delegate_to_a_project_configurator_.28recommended.29)) and set it to `execute` and `runOnIncremental`, so that also aspects are (re-)applied when coding and testing in Eclipse (using m2e)