# Dagger2 on an AJC maven-compiled project

Tags: maven, guice, aspectj, dagger-2

Due to inter-type declarations the project I'm currently working on has it's `pom.xml` set to use `ajc` disabling `javac`.

```
// disable javac
<build>
   ...
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>default-compile</id>
                <phase>none</phase>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

We were planing to use Dagger2 but that would require to put `dagger-compiler` as an `<annotationProcessorPaths>` to be used by the disabled `javac`.

As `aspectj-maven-plugin` does not support the required `<annotationProcessorPaths>` I'm a bit at lost here. Any simple solution I'm not seeing or should I simply go with Guice?

Comment: You could try configuring to have the Java compiler do the annotation processing and the AspectJ compiler doing the compilation as I [described it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47291878/2699901) earlier for another question. You might see slower compilation times depending on the number of generated classes and the complexity of the generated code. Your mileage might vary.

Comment: @NándorElődFekete, thanks for comment. Looked promising but either AspectJ doesn't compile or if it does compile Dagger2 won't run. I've gone with Guice...

Comment: I never used Dagger2 or even know what it is, but the question seems interesting. Please share an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub and I (or maybe Nándor, if he is faster) will take a look.