# How to use weaven with aspectJ in compiletime in spring project

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop, aspectj-maven-plugin

We are using `Spring` and we used `Spring AOP`. Due to the nature of `Spring AOP` which uses `Proxy` we reached the limitation of it when tring to warp `join point` on call inside a call.
i.e 
  **aspect on B execution will not run if A is being call**

```
public void A(){
   B()
}
public void B(){
}
```

In order to solves this issue we are using `ApsectJ` weaven in compile time.

Which is work good. But then, the issue is make it play nice with `Spring Bean` i.e let the `Autowired` work in side the aspect class.

## Pom.xml Maven plugin

```
        <!-- AspectJ configuration -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

## EDIT

duplicate of [Spring autowired bean for @Aspect aspect is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633840/spring-autowired-bean-for-aspect-aspect-is-null)

[info on how to get aspectj to work with maven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12537656/1211174)

Answer (score 0):

## Use AspectJ in compile time and make sure spring autowired magic will work

According to the `AspectJ` doc [aspectOf Chapter](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/ataspectj-aspectof.html). In order to some module to known that aspect is an aspect of something one should use `aspectOf`. `Spring` has the `feature`

```
 <bean id="a" class="com.someinterface.A" factory-method="aspectOf"></bean>
```

This will result the A of above to be a `Spring Bean` and as a bonus `Spring` will know that this is an `aspect` of some other code. This is enough for `Spring` to use the `Autowire` **magic** inside of an aspect.

**NOTE** that using `aspectOf` requires `xml configuration`. I tried to get the same result with `@Configurable` but it did not work. if some one has some info on that it will great. :)

## Bonus - Use `Spring AOP` proxy for aspect(in run time)

Set `spring` to scan `@Aspect` and make it a spring bean

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.centure" >
     <context:include-filter type="annotation"     expression="org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect"/> 
</context:component-scan>
```

### in this case every thing will work out of the box

```
private SomeService service;
public SomeService getService() {
    return service;
}

@Autowired
public void setService(SomeService) {
    this.service = service;
}
@Aspect
public class myAspect {
    @Pointcut("execution(public * com.myinterface.save(..))")
         public void save() {
    }

@Around("myAspect () && args(thearg)")
public Object doBasicProfiling(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, TheObject thearg)
         throws Throwable {

    Object retVal = null;
    try {
        retVal = pjp.proceed();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return retVal;
    }
```